MongoDB to BigQuery connector: _id recieved not hashed
While using the connector and returning the data without being flattened, I'm recieving ObjectIds like this
"_id":{"timestamp":1638209485,"counter":13050635,"randomValue1":12445288,"randomValue2":25}

instead of the hash I see in MongoDB. How can I fix this?

I think the format is the internal representation of ObjectId. May I know how the value comes as-is? Is that some export option from MongoDB or the connector?

I don't see any option that forces that internal representation, no. I'm expecting to recieve a hash like 619e85aeb5d2519660f8bb52, but instead I recieve that internal representation. Not sure how to recieve the hash string instead.
